# How to deploy an .appx to a Windows Phone 8.1 via e-mail?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, appx

I just e-mailed a .appx file, created using App Studio, to my phone. When I tap it the phone ask if I want to search the Store for an app to open the file with.

Is this just a bug in the Preview of Windows Phone 8.1 or am I doing something wrong? The certificate from App Studio is installed on the phone.

Answer (score -2):

You can't install XAPs or APPXs directly from the phone. You'll need to use the application deployment tool, if it's not going through the Store.

Comment: "Enrolling users for company app distribution" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx tells me otherwise. Seems like it's a known issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/4cde8840-6ea1-4566-9ee6-fd1d5c281211/notice-known-issue-with-qrurl-sideloading-81-apps-dev-preview-os?forum=wpappstudio